# Storing and Processing Images/Videos on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I am developing a facebook application,which fetches users images and process it using OpenCV.
On my local machine:

1)Application download user image from facebook on E:/(specific folder for each user)

2)OpenCv fetches images from the folder and cartoonise it

Where to Host this type of application, i am using django,facebook-sdk.

How to do same in Heroku?

Comment: Heroku does not support to save any data on their server. If you save any image or file then it will be deleted whenever Heroku Dyno is restarted. And as per Heroku documentation every Dyno on Heroku will definitely restart once in a day. On Heroku the approach should be to save all images or files on Amazon S3 or any other cloud storage.

Comment: thanks,this was the answer i was looking for